# How to Install Sqoop in Windows system and what are all necessary things it requires?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, sqoop, mapr

I tried to install sqoop for that I was referring to some installation guide that says HBase and mapr to be installed as prerequisite. I am not understanding how to proceed. So can some one guide me how to Install Sqoop in Windows system and what are all necessary things it requires?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play/debug with Sqoop/Hadoop on Windows - you can install the HDInsight Emulator on your machine. This will install a singe node Hadoop deployment that includes sqoop and sqoop connector.

The following post which I have written can guide you through the process. It shows how to install Hadoop and SQL Express on your dev box and how to import/export data via Sqoop.

http://aviadezra.blogspot.com/2014/01/hdinsight-emulator-sqoop-with-sql.html

HTH
AViad